# Как открывать боковое меню слева на право в bootstrap 5.1?

Tags: bootstrap, framework, menu, bootstrap5

Всем привет! В [bootstrap 5.1 добавили боковое меню](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#offcanvas), открывается только справа на лево.
Как открывать меню слева на право?

Comment: Для примера можно было указать код стандартного открытия

Comment: Даже ссылка не та. Похоже вы ищите `offcanvas`, а не `navbar`.